# Error loading assembly when retrieving from AppFabric cache

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, appfabric

I ran into a weird issue today while debugging one of my projects. I use VS2010 / windows 7 home premium.

I have a project that uses Windows Server AppFabric Cache. I have configured everything, and have created two different C# projects (2 solutions) to test the AppFabric configuration. The project names are "AppFabricServer" and "AppFabricClient". This is just for testing and the naming convention doesn't mean anything specific. I use "AppFabricServer" to Add objects to AppFabric Cache and "AppFabricClient" project to retrieve.

Now, the problem is after running the "AppFabricServer" and then I try to run "AppFabricClient" after closing the "AppFabricServer", I get an error "**System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AppFabricServer**". I don't understand in which way "AppFabricServer" project is related to "AppFabricClient" project.

The same thing happens vice-verse also - this means, after restarting the computer and if I run "AppFabricClient" project first (it also has a Cache writing module), I am not able to run "AppFabricServer" project (it has a Cache reading module as well). I get the same error -"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AppFabricClient".

The exception is thrown at the line where I try to retrieve data from the Cache - when I call the Get method of DataCache.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What objects are you saving into the cache? What is the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppFabric utilizes the [NetDataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx) to serialize objects.  This serializer encodes CLR type information.  So, even if the shape of your objects is the same, it actually requires them to be the same types in the same assembly.

Therefore, take the object you are serializing out of the AppFabricServer assembly and put it in a third assembly that is referenced from both the AppFabricServer and AppFabricClient programs.  That way, the CLR type information will be the same in both.

Comment: @Craig Is that serialiser setting documented anywhere?

Comment: idk.  I just remember happening across it in a blog post somewhere.